# Multisite, multiple domains per site

Tags: multisite, redirect

I currently have a multisite install with 4 sites and 4 domains, like so:

`Site 1` -> `site1.com`

`Site 2` -> `site2.com`

`Site 3` -> `site3.com`

`Site 4` -> `site4.com`

There was a typo in the domain of `Site 3`, so we changed `site3.com` to `site3-new.com`. So far so good. Now we want `site3-new.com` to show `Site 3`, and we want `site3.com` to show `site3-new.com`.

That last step is causing me endless headache. What's happening right now is that visiting `site3-new.com` opens up `Site 3`, while visiting `site3.com` opens `Site 1` (it redirects 302 to `site1.com`), presumably because in wp-config `site1.com` is set as `'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE'`.

What can I do to show 1 site from the multisite instalation for 2 separate domains?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried an .htaccess redirect? If you place it in the root folder of site3.com and 301 redirect everything to site3-new.com that should do it.

Comment: You need to show your wp-config.php custom settings.  If you are using multiple domains, you cannot set DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE to a static setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vanilla WP, a site cannot serve multiple domains like that unless it's the root site.

Additionally, your desired setup would lead you to one of two situations:

1. You're succesfully serving the site on 2 domains, but all the canonical tags point to the first domain regardless of which is setup
2. Google sees duplicated content and hits both sites with an SEO penalty

Which leads us to the SEO friendly, simpler more performant solution:

Set up your Host to ***redirect*** `site3.com` to `site3-new.com`, and only serve WP from `site3-new.com`. Any visitors to `site3.com` would get a 301 redirect to `site3-new.com`. This updates all the search engine results too.

You can do this via Nginx or HTAccess rules, but most hosts have a point and click option to do this in their hosting panels, even some DNS providers will do this for you.

Otherwise you would need to install a plugin for doman mapping. But this would be an inferior solution for your problem with various disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to have multiple domains on the same Multisite installation is to have a different network for each domain using https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/.

details of the wp-config.php setup is (including DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE) is here
https://github.com/stuttter/wp-multi-network#domainsub-domain-flexibility

But over all it depends on what interaction you want between the sites.